# How to filter results of this SQL query?

Tags: sql, windows

I've run a query to calculate the difference between values of two columns from two tables using a common key. The query is:

**Select a.GPID, a.StartDate-b.StartDate as Discrepancy FROM Difftable1 a
INNER JOIN Difftable2 b
ON a.GPID= b.GPID;**

and the results are here:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Gg0.png)

But I want to filter the results to only include differences which equal -10000. Every attempt results in a syntax error. I'm new to SQL.

Comment: Hi have you tried `Where a.StartDate - b.StartDate = -10000`  You really should show the failed attempts and their errors - that way we don't need to repeat your errors and can possibly tell you why they resulted in errors!

Comment: Hah, I swear I tried that and was confounded when it didn't work. I must have made a typo somewhere, because I just pasted your solution and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Keep calm and sql on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter out -10000 from the result set, you can use

```
SELECT a.GPID, a.StartDate-b.StartDate as Discrepancy 
FROM Difftable1 a 
    INNER JOIN Difftable2 b ON a.GPID= b.GPID
WHERE a.StartDate-b.StartDate != -10000;
```

If you want to have records in the result set with only -10000, then replace != with = at the end of the above statement.

Comment: Thank you Sankar. If you don't mind-- what If I want to also include the rest of the columns in the results? There are 3 other columns in each table but they aren't displayed in the results because of the way I structured the query.

Comment: You can try 
SELECT a.StartDate-b.StartDate as Discrepancy, a.*
FROM Difftable1 a 
    INNER JOIN Difftable2 b ON a.GPID= b.GPID
WHERE a.StartDate-b.StartDate != -10000;

Comment: You can add columns from table Difftable2 by adding,b.* to the selection like SELECT a.StartDate-b.StartDate as Discrepancy, a.*, b.*